# Submitting Modal Form not working in Laravel

Tags: php, forms, bootstrap-modal, laravel-5.4

I am trying to submit a modal form in Laravel.  For some reason, it is not working.  Below is my code for the Modal form.

```
<div class="modal-body">
            <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
              </button>
              <strong>Hurry!</strong> Early bird registration ends in 2 days.
            </div>
            {{-- Registration form goes here --}}
            <form action="{{ url('contact')}}" method="POST">
              {{ csrf_field() }}
              <h5 class="mb-2">Basic Info</h5>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name">Name:</label>
                <input type="name" class="form-control" id="name">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email">Email:</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label name="message">Message:</label>
                <input id="subject" name="subject" class="form-control">
              </div>
```

Now my routes are as follows:

```
Route::get('contact', 'PagesController@getContact');
Route::post('contact', 'PagesController@postContact');
```

And in my controller I have the following code:

```
public function getContact()
{
  return view('pages.contact');
 }
  public function postContact(Request $request)
 {
   $this->validate($request,
  ['email'=>'required|email',
'name'=> 'min:3',
'message'=> 'min:10']);
$data = array(
  'email' => $request->email,
  'name' => $request->name,
  'bodyMessage'=> $request->message
);
Mail::send('emails.contact', $data, function($message) use ($data){
  $message->from($data['email']);
  $message->to('sammie@me.com');
  $message->subject($data['name']);
});
return redirect('/')->with('success', 'Thanks! Your message has been sent');
}
```

Do I need to do anything else as it is a modal form?

Comment: What error do you get?

Answer (score 1):

you didn't give the `name` atrribute to your `input` tags. when the `form` has been submitted, each value is identified with it's name. So change your input elements

```
<input type="name" class="form-control" id="name">
<input type="email" class="form-control" id="email">
<input id="subject" name="subject" class="form-control">
```

with

```
<input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name">
<input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="email">
<input type="text" name="message" class="form-control" id="message">
```

Answer (score 1):

you dont have name attribute in name and email and change the subject to message

```
<form action="{{ url('contact')}}" method="POST">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <h5 class="mb-2">Basic Info</h5>
    <div class="form-group">
       <label for="name">Name:</label>
       <input type="name" name="name" class="form-control" id="name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
       <label for="email">Email:</label>
       <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="email">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
       <label name="message">Message:</label>
       <input id="subject" name="message" class="form-control">
    </div>
```

Comment: Now have to work out how to do a select.  Thanks for your help Raushan.